# Does this quantity have a meaning or relation to something else?

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, information-theory

$X$ is a discrete random variable taking values in $\{0,1,2,3,\ldots\}$ with a probability mass function $p_X(n)$.  Let

$$U_k(X)=\sum_{n=k}^\infty\sqrt{np_X(n)p_X(n-k)}$$

where $k$ is a positive integer.

This came up in the course of information theory research (with $k=1$ and $k=2$ in my case).  Has anyone ever seen this quantity anywhere?  Can anyone see relationships to other statistics of $X$ (maybe bounds using mean/variance/etc)?  I am dumbfounded and don't know what to do with this thing...